# Factorial simplificaton involving negative 1

Tags: factorial

What is the best way of simplifying

$$\dfrac{(a+b-1)!}{(b-1)!}$$

Ideally i want to get rid of the two $-1$ and the final solution should not containt the gamma function

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ positive integers, because in the case you should find it easy to cancel out the denominator.

Comment: Yes, i now get 
$$\dfrac{b*(a+b−1)!}{(b)!}$$
What should be my next step

Comment: Your expression is as simple as it can be, I'm afraid.

Comment: Well, you can write it as: $$\frac{b*(a+b)!}{(a+b)*b!}$$

Comment: M.Wind that is fantastic, exactly the form i was after! is there any other forms i can write this without the -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a!~{a+b\choose a}\frac b{a+b}~=~a!~{a+b\choose b}\frac b{a+b}$$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers:
$$
\frac{(a+b-1)!}{(b-1)!}=b(1+b)(2+b)\cdot\ldots\cdot(a-1+b).
$$

Comment: I would argue that is not more simple, can you consider leaving it in terms of factorials

Comment: I am afraid, but if you want to get rid of the fraction, then you have to write it as a product like I did. If not, then your original expression (or that in the comment) is as simple as possible.

Comment: Is there not away to remove the -1 from the top?

Comment: Only if you erase it, @MathsPro...what's so terrible about that poor $\;-1\;$ in the expression?!

Comment: Its part of a giant expression im working on and that contains factorials involcing a and b everywhere, im hoping removing it from this will create alot of cancelling.

Comment: maybe you write down the complete expression?